# What is a better way to operate my data in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have `n` subjects for each subject we have 2 types of measurement at different time points with different lengths. All the values are double, and time points are int.

For example,

> subject 1
>
> Measure 1:
>
> Value: 1.1, 0.25, 0.7
>
> Time:   0, 12, 35
>
> Mesure 2:
>
> Value: 2.2, 1.8, 0.95,0.4
>
> Time: 3, 10,33,40
>
> Subject 2:
>
> Measure 1:
>
> Value: 1.4, 1.25, 0.9,1.7,1.1
>
> Time:   0, 12,
>   35,40,45
>
> Mesure 2:
>
> Value: 0.2, 1.1, 0.35
>
> Time: 7, 15,23

Should I vector of vector or there are some way to store these data and access easily?

EDIT: From this question, I learned to use structure and class to store and operate data.

Comment: The answer depends mostly on how you want to access/analyze the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple class containing the two member variables and make a set() and get() method for each of the variables.

You can then decide to create a vector with the pointers to each object

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to attain this structure of data.
One of ways maybe look as follow:

```
    typedef struct {
        vector<double> Value;
        vector<int> Time;
    }Measurement;

    typedef struct {
        Measurement measure1;
        Measurement measure2;
    }Subject;
```